# Short List of Figures in Memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, tocloft

I really like the appearance of the short list of contents, introduced in the `memoir` manual. What I want is a short list of figures command changing the LoF style similarly. Centered captions followed by page numbers, without these dots in between.
I was trying to adopt the code of the short toc command, but it didn't work out.
Here is the shorttoc command.

```
\documentclass [a4paper,11pt,oneside]{memoir}
\setsecnumdepth{section}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% Short and long ToC
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\setupshorttoc}{%
  \renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Short contents}
  \let\oldchangetocdepth\changetocdepth
  \let\oldprecistoctext\precistoctext
  \renewcommand{\precistoctext}[1]{}
  \let\oldcftchapterfillnum\cftchapterfillnum
  \renewcommand*{\changetocdepth}[1]{}
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{0}% chapters
  \renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\hfill\sffamily}
  \renewcommand*{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}
  \renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{ \textperiodcentered\space}
  \renewcommand*{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
%%  \setpnumwidth{0em}
%%  \setpnumwidth{1.5em}
  \renewcommand*{\cftchapterfillnum}[1]{%
    {\cftchapterleader}\nobreak
    \hbox to 1.5em{\cftchapterpagefont ##1\hfil}\cftchapterafterpnum\par}
  \setrmarg{0.3\textwidth}
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\@tocrmarg}
  \addtolength{\unitlength}{1.5em}
  \let\oldcftpartformatpnum\cftpartformatpnum
  \renewcommand*{\cftpartformatpnum}[1]{%
    \hbox to\unitlength{{\cftpartpagefont ##1}}}
  \let\oldcftbookformatpnum\cftbookformatpnum
  \renewcommand*{\cftbookformatpnum}[1]{%
    \hbox to\unitlength{{\cftbookpagefont ##1}}}}

\newcommand*{\setupparasubsecs}{%
  \let\oldnumberline\numberline
  \renewcommand*{\cftsubsectionfont}{\itshape}
  \renewcommand*{\cftsubsectionpagefont}{\itshape}
  \renewcommand{\l@subsection}[2]{
    \ifnum\c@tocdepth > 1\relax
      \def\numberline####1{\textit{####1}~}%
      \leftskip=\cftsubsectionindent
      \rightskip=\@tocrmarg
%%      \advance\rightskip 0pt plus \hsize % uncomment this for raggedright
%%      \advance\rightskip 0pt plus 2em    % uncomment this for semi-ragged
      \parfillskip=\fill
      \ifhmode ,\ \else\noindent\fi
      \ignorespaces
      {\cftsubsectionfont ##1}~{\cftsubsectionpagefont##2}%
       \let\numberline\oldnumberline\ignorespaces
    \fi}}

\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\par}}%%% OK

\newcommand*{\setupmaintoc}{%
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}
  \let\changetocdepth\oldchangetocdepth
  \let\precistoctext\oldprecistoctext
  \let\cftchapterfillnum\oldcftchapterfillnum
  \addtodef{\cftchapterbreak}{\par}{}
  \renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}
  \renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{\sffamily\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}
  \renewcommand*{\cftchapterafterpnum}{}
  \renewcommand{\cftchapterbreak}{\par\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}}
  \setpnumwidth{2.55em}
  \setrmarg{3.55em}
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
  \let\cftpartformatpnum\oldcftpartformatpnum
  \addtodef{\cftpartbreak}{\par}{}
  \let\cftbookformatpnum\oldcftbookformatpnum
  \addtodef{\cftbookbreak}{\par}{}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setupshorttoc
\tableofcontents

\setupparasubsecs
\setupmaintoc
\tableofcontents
\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}
%%%%%% Test
\chapter{Chaper 1}
\section{Section2}
\subsection{Subsection3}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\section{Section2}
\section{Section1}
\end{document}
```

And here is something I tried.

```
\documentclass [a4paper,11pt,oneside]{memoir}\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\setupshortlof}{%

\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{ShortLof}
\let\oldchangelofdepth\changelofdepth
\let\oldprecisloftext\precisloftext
\renewcommand{\precisloftext}[1]{}
\let\oldcftchapterfillnum\cftchapterfillnum
% \renewcommand*{\changelofdepth}[1]{}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}% chapters
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\hfill\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{ \textperiodcentered\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\clearpage
\setupshortlof
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

This doesn't work at all.

Has anyone here already done such a thing or knows how to do it?

---

#### Update:

Thx so far. This one works fine.

```
\documentclass [a4paper,11pt,oneside]{memoir} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Short LoF
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\setupshortlof}{%
\renewcommand*{\listfigurename}{ShortLof}
%\let\oldchangelofdepth\changelofdepth
%\let\oldcftfigurefillnum\cftfigurefillnum
\renewcommand*{\cftfigurefont}{\hfill\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\cftfigurepagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\cftfigureleader}{ \textperiodcentered\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftfigureafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand*{\cftfigurefillnum}[1]{%
{\cftfigureleader}\nobreak
\hbox to 1.5em{\cftfigurepagefont ##1\hfil}\cftfigureafterpnum\par}
\setrmarg{0.3\textwidth}
\setlength{\unitlength}{\@tocrmarg}
\addtolength{\unitlength}{1.5em}
\let\oldcftpartformatpnum\cftpartformatpnum
 \renewcommand*{\cftpartformatpnum}[1]{%
\hbox to\unitlength{{\cftpartpagefont ##1}}}
 \let\oldcftbookformatpnum\cftbookformatpnum
 \renewcommand*{\cftbookformatpnum}[1]{%
 \hbox to\unitlength{{\cftbookpagefont ##1}}}
 }
 \makeatother
 \begin{document}

 \clearpage
 \setupshortlof
 \listoffigures
 \chapter{Chaper1}
 \section{Section1}
 \begin{figure}
 \caption{Test1}%
 \label{Test1}%
 \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}
  \caption{Test2}%
  \label{Test2}%
 \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}
 \caption{Test3}%
 \label{Test3}%
 \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

Now I'd like to get rid of the figure numbers. I don't want them to be displayed in the LoF. How can I do this?

Comment: Works fine ;-), but chapters have nothing to do with figures, change `chapter` to `figure`, and as far as I know there is no precis for the lof, and change `\listfigurename` not `\contentsname`

Comment: @user4285: Welcome to tex.sx! A suggestion: Change your username to something more telling than "user4285".

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your definition of `\setupshortlof`:

```
\renewcommand*{\cftfigurepresnum}{\expandafter\@gobbletwo\@gobble}
```

Comment: Nice. Now it works perfect!

Comment: @RolandD: Please consider marking my answer  as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below the vote count.